# Is there a Sqlite 3 query or performance analyzer for iPhone applications?

Tags: ios, performance, sqlite

Are there any tools to measure performance of DB queries on a Sqlite 3 database?
I'm thinking of something where you would feed it with a database and some queries and it will tell you, "slow, because you are missing an index on this and that".

Any ideas?

Comment: I always thought that's what books are for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If you're using Core Data (with SQLite):**

Add the following line to your app's *Arguments Passed On Lunch*:

```
-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 1
```

See [Debugging Core Data on the iPhone](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/3/11/debugging-core-data-on-the-iphone.html).

---

**If you're using SQLite directly:**

See SQLite's [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html).

Comment: Not quite what I was after but perfectly does what I want.